# Why does using `solve` with a multivariate system of equations error unexpectedly?

Tags: matlab, solver

While trying to solve a system of equations with 2 variables and 2 unknowns (Izhikevich nullclines), I encountered an unexpected error: `Warning: 4 equations in 2 variables.` and `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.`

This is unexpected because as I stated, I was providing only 2 equations with the 2 variables, which should be a well-formed system of equations.

My relevant lines of code are as follows:

`syms uu vv
[solvv, soluu] = solve([0.04*vv^2 + 5*vv + 140 - uu + I(t) == 0, a(t)*(b(t)*vv - uu) == 0], [vv, uu]);`

The complete error trace is:

`Warning: 4 equations in 2 variables. 
\> In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p>symengine at 54
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 97
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 150
  In solve at 160
  In Q3_new at 37
  In run at 64 
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
\> In solve at 169
  In Q3_new at 37
  In run at 64`

Confused, I went to MATLAB's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) for `solve` and tried using the example snippet for solving a multivariate system of equations:

`syms u v
[solv, solu] = solve([2*u^2 + v^2 == 0, u - v == 1], [v, u])`

The expected output of this snippet, according to the documentation, is:

`solv =
 - (2^(1/2)*1i)/3 - 2/3
   (2^(1/2)*1i)/3 - 2/3
solu =
 1/3 - (2^(1/2)*1i)/3
 (2^(1/2)*1i)/3 + 1/3`

but the snippit instead returns:

`Warning: 4 equations in 2 variables. 
\> In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\symbolic\symbolic\symengine.p>symengine at 54
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.evalin at 97
  In mupadengine.mupadengine>mupadengine.feval at 150
  In solve at 160 
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
\> In solve at 169`

`solv =`

`[ empty sym ]`

`solu =`

`[]`

as before.

Now I know I'm not making some beginner's mistake with my code because even the example code errors in the same way. Calling the singlevariate example snippit works as expected. I have tried this with MATLAB 2012a and MATLAB 2014a.

What could explain this unusual behaviour?

Comment: for symbolic solutions Mathematica is probably a better choice

Comment: Despite what @madbitloman says, Matab's Symbolic Math tool box is a perfectly good choice for systems like this. However, you need to look at the correct documentation. You say that you're using R2014a, but you linked to the documentation for the current version of Matlab, R2015a. If you're using an older version of Matlab, you should not rely on Google. Just type `doc solve` in your command window to read the full documentation for your version. Archived documentation is also available online [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html).

Comment: I don't have a logon to access the archived documentation because I'm using my academic institution's MATLAB license.

Comment: @StockB: I also use an academic version at my university. You may just need to create a MathWorks account. In any case, `doc solve` in your Command Window will work.

Comment: Thanks, I learned about the `doc` command today! I previously knew of `help` but HTML format is much nicer to read in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can duplicate this on MATLAB 2014a. I found that if I already defined the variables using `syms` you can let `solve` resolve the variables automatically.

```
syms u v
[sv, su] = solve([2*u^2 + v^2 == 0, u - v == 1], [v, u]) % Doesn't work

% works but order-unspecified so this is not desirable
[su, sv] = solve([2*u^2 + v^2 == 0, u - v == 1])
```

Another user points out a mistake in using the incorrect documentation. [MATLAB 2014a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/symbolic/solve.html) uses the following notation instead for re-ordered solutions. The other form seems to be for 2015. You should probably verify this holds true in 2012a but it seems to do [so](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html)

```
syms u v
[sv, su] = solve([2*u^2 + v^2 == 0, u - v == 1], v, u)
```

Comment: You say that you're using R2014a, but you linked to the documentation for the current version of Matlab, R2015a. Here is the [archived documentation for `solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/symbolic/solve.html) in R2014a. You'll see that the example that you pointed to is *not* present.

Comment: Aha. caught. Did not expect that change. Noted.

Comment: I cannot access the archived documentation as I am merely a user, and not the holder of the license.

Comment: I think the change occurred because many users didn't understand the difference between solving for `u` and `v` and a two-element vector.